# What 64bit target to choose when compiling with Visual Studio (vcvarsall.bat)?

Tags: 64-bit, x86-64, itanium

The `vcvarsall.bat` that does setup de build environment let you choose between `x86 | ia64 | amd64 | x86_amd64 | x86_ia64`.

First option is obvious for 32bit, but the question is: what would be the optimal option between the other 4 if you want to build for 64bit and you want to run on all 64 bit machines.

Let say that you don't have time/resources to make 4 builds for 64 and you have to choose only one of them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a page that clarifies this issue http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s%28VS.80%29.aspx

- 32/64 OS building for 32 => `x86`
- 32 OS building for 64 => `x86_amd64`
- 64 OS building for 64 => `amd64`

And you can ignore the other options because Itanium does not have a real market share.

Comment: Interestingly however, `Visual Studio uses the 32-bit cross compiler even on a Windows 64-bit computer.` from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246588(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

ia64 (Itanium) is a very redundant CPU (Google for ia64 market share) and you should use it only if you're going to deploy to that architecture.

x86_amd is for running 32 bit on amd64 architecture, use it only if your code doesn't compile/work under amd64.

Comment: I already found a page on MSDN describing this. Regarding Itanium you are right.